# Trouble trying to define a Subquery in Linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I would like to know how can I define a Correlated Subquery in LINQ to access two tables in my database.

What I intend to do is to create the following query in LINQ

```
select * from Value
where CyberEntityID IN (select CyberEntityID from CyberEntity where 
                        datetimevalue >= '2017-05-04 17:11:32.960' and 
                        datetimevalue <= '2017-05-04 17:11:33.035')
```

In my code I have the following query

```
var query = dc.Values.Where(h => h.CyberEntityID == dc.CyberEntities
                                 .Where(d => d.datetimevalue >= sd && d.datetimevalue <= ed)
                                 .Select(d => d.CyberEntityID)).ToList();
```

However I'm getting an error saying

> the operator == cannot be applied to int and IQueryable types

.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Where` method is returning an `IQueryable` of `CyberEntityID` that cannot be compared with `h.CyberEntityID` so you need the [`FirsOrDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx) after `Select` which returns the **first** element of the **sequence**:

```
.Select(d => d.CyberEntityID).FirstOrDefault()
```

Or use [`Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
.Where(h => dc.CyberEntities.Where(d => d.datetimevalue >= sd && d.datetimevalue <= ed)
                            .Select(d => d.CyberEntityID).Contains(h.CyberEntityID))
```

Comment: Can he have a `First()` instead?

Comment: Doesn't this only returns me one row from CyberEntity table? In my database I have 3 rows for the date range that was given in the example. For each of those 3 rows I want to select all the related values (which would be 50 * 3 in my case). I thought about using FirstOrDefault() but I didn't know if I would get 150 or 50 values (for this example).

Comment: @DiogoMartinho In this case use `Contains` method. Check my updated answer.

Comment: @JoePhillips I would prefer to use `FirstOrDefault` so it returns a default value if the sequence contains no elements. However check my updated answer.based on the OP's comment.